# Number of times letter "a" and "t" occurs in upper and lower cases

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

A program with 10 names.
If the name has more than 5 letters, then print the number of letters "a" and "t" no matter in upper or lower case. 
If the name begins with "A" and has 5 or fewer letters, the output is "Uninteresting name"

Comment: What is your question? Did you try to do this task that you describe? Did it work? If not, what was the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming "A program with 10 names" means that you have a list of names of length 10, you could:

- Iterate over names, that is a simple `for` loop.
- Check the conditions you mentioned to distinguish among 3 cases:

  - Case "has more than 5 letters" -> print the number of letters "a" and "t" (use `count` method of `str`)
  - Case "begins with "A" and has 5 or fewer letters" -> print "Uninteresting name"
  - Otherwise -> just ignored (since not mentioned in your question)

To do what you're trying to achieve, you don't need to keep capital letters, so you can just `lower()` any name.

Here you go:

```
names = [
    "Athena",
    "Artemis",
    "Ares",
    "Apollo",
    "Demeter",
    "Dionysus",
    "Hades",
    "Hermes",
    "Poseidon",
    "Zeus",
    ]

# Check names
for name in names:
    low_name = name.lower()
    if len(name) > 5:
        print(f'{name}\t| # of "A": {low_name.count("a")}\t-\t# of "T": {low_name.count("t")}')
    elif name.startswith('a'):
        print("Uninteresting name")
    # Ignore any other name, or add an 'else' to manage it
```

Output:

```
Athena      | # of "A": 2   -   # of "T": 1
Artemis     | # of "A": 1   -   # of "T": 1
Uninteresting name
Apollo      | # of "A": 1   -   # of "T": 0
Demeter     | # of "A": 0   -   # of "T": 1
Dionysus    | # of "A": 0   -   # of "T": 0
Hermes      | # of "A": 0   -   # of "T": 0
Poseidon    | # of "A": 0   -   # of "T": 0
```

*Note skipped names (lenght <= 5, not starting with "A"): Hades, Zeus*

Answer (score -2):

```
name = input("name: ")
counter = 0
for i in name:
    if len(name) > 5 and i == "a" or i == "A":
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```

First you get the name from the user. Then you create a counter variable for all the "a"s in the name. Afterwards, you iterate over the inputted name and check if the length of the name is > 5 and if the current character is equal to an lower or uppercase a. If true, then you increase counter by 1. Last you print the counter of the "a"s in the name